# set element visibility with one statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of doing this

```
if (showElement) $el.show() else $el.hide();
```

Is there a built in function that can be used something like this ?

```
$el.makeVisible(showElement);
```

Comment: Did you try looking through the manual? http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/basics/ It's right beside `show` and `hide`.

Comment: I knew of .toggle, but didn't know it can take a bool param.  Thanks for your helpfull comment.

Comment: It's the forth variation of toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to do this

```
$el.toggle(showElement)
```

Comment: you are always the fastest gunner :)

Answer (score 4):

Use toggle():

```
$el.toggle(showElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$el.toggle(showElement)
```

Comment: @David - It does, you pass a boolean as a switch, either calling hide or show based on the passed boolean etc.